# Is it a Mitzvah to tell a fellow Jew “have a wonderful day”?

Tags: mitzvah, middos-character-traits, bein-adam-lachavero, chesed-kindness

Is it considered a Mitzvah/Chesed to tell a fellow Jew to have a great day? It sounds like a simple thing, but I thought it would be included under Viohavta Lireiacha Kamocha, no?

Comment: Would you consider "have a wonderful/great day" under the category/statement of, וֶהֱוֵי מְקַבֵּל אֶת כָּל הָאָדָם בְּסֵבֶר פָּנִים יָפוֹת (Pirkei Avot 1:15) or הֱוֵי מַקְדִּים בִּשְׁלוֹם כָּל אָדָם (Pikrei avot 4:15, and also Brachot 17a)? If not, I would say its a big chesed to say such words.

Comment: Rambam Deos chapter 6 halacha 3

Comment: How would that be included in Viohavta Lireiacha Kamocha? You can love him and not say 'have a woderful day'.